# regex - How to filter number and "-"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Im trying to filter only numbers and the `-`. Whenever the user inputs anything that is not a number and not a hyphen/dash it should be removed. I have the regex `[0-9\-]` but its not working. I  know its wrong but Im really new to this.

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/nqdjZ/

Plase help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change regular Expression -

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^([0-9_\\-]+)$");
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `new RegExp` expects a string; you should use the literal `/[0-9-]/` instead. The next problem is that `replace` shouldn't even be there. Another one is that you can never be entirely sure where the text is being typed - don't assume it's at the end. That will seriously annoy people.

Use an `<input type="number">` instead, and validate at the end instead of while someone's typing.

Comment: `/[0-9\-]/` should be the regex if it's a literal. Don't forget to escape the '-' character.

Comment: @neouser99: It doesn't matter at the start or at the end :) And the `+` won't matter, since it's not anchored.

Comment: @minitech Do you mean to say that I shouldn't do new RegExp but something like var patter = /[0-9-]/;

Comment: @TheOnlyIdiot: Yes. (And if you were to do `new RegExp`, you need to pass it a string, so you would quote it. But don't use the constructor unless you need a dynamic regular expression! In a string, you have to double-escape the backslashes.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
[^\d\-]+
```

and replace with null string.

explain:

> ***`[^character_group]`***
>   Negation: Matches any single character that is not in `character_group`.
>
> ***`\d`***
>   Matches any decimal digit.
>
> ***`+`***
>   Matches the previous element one or more times.
>
> ***`\-`*** 
>   Matches `-`

and your code:

```
result = inputString.replace(/[^\d\-]+/g, "");
```